# How to name an object out of a string in R

Tags: r, string, object

I am working on a loop over a number of spss datasets. 
The loop needs to open each dataset and give it a specific object name.
What I cannot get right is to move a value that is string to become the object's/dataset's name.

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
#how to name an object out of a string in R
list_of_dataset_names <- list.files(path = folder)
for (dataset in list_of_dataset_names) {
   # dataset name = my_dataset_june2016.sav
   temp_name <- read.spss(dataset)
   new_R_object_name <- grepl('.sav', '', dataset) 
   # new_R_object_name is 'my_dataset_june2016'
   # how do I make the string contained by 'new_R_object_name', the object name of the temp_name ?
 }
```

I have tried this https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/ but it is about taking the object's name and converting it into a string rather than attaching a string value as the new name of an existing object.

Thank you in advance.

------ EDIT ------

It is indeed a duplicate, I was not able to find that link.

The code tha resolved the issue on my end is:

```
assign(new_R_object_name, temp_name)
```

Comment: Append datasets to a list and name list elements as dataset names

Comment: You *can* do this (and the duplicate will show you how), but you'll be better off using a single named `list`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I like the idea of a list, I will give it a try